# onChange function not passing ID on selecting an option

Tags: jquery, jsp

I want to get ID passed from .jsp file to .js on selection of an option in page using `change` function or `on('change', function(){})`. My code is below:

.jsp file

```
<select class="form-control" id="access_user">
        <option selected disabled>Select User</option>
        <c:forEach var="user" items="${userList}" varStatus="">
               <option onchange="getUserID('this','${user.userId}')">${user.username}</option>
        </c:forEach>
</select>
```

My function in `.js` file is as follows:

```
$("#access_user").on('change', function getUserID(that, Uid) {
    console.log("User id = ", Uid)
});
```

I am unable to get Uid in console, which I am getting in `.jsp` file.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be a rather confused mix of native JS and jQuery.

To achieve what you require simply add the `change` event handler *only* to the `select`. You can remove the `on*` event attributes, as they should be avoided where possible.

To get the selected `${user.userId}` you can set it as the `value` of the `option` elements. Then you can retrieve it simply using the `val()` method of your jQuery code. Try this:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="access_user">
  <option selected disabled>Select User</option>
  <c:forEach var="user" items="${userList}" varStatus="">
    <option val="${user.userId}">${user.username}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

```js
$("#access_user").on('change', function() {
  var uid = $(this).val();
  console.log("User id = ", uid)
});
```